# Is waiting for return, ok?

Tags: java, firebase

Some main code with the first firebase call:

```
     refFB.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName) {
                FirebaseReq fbReq = snapshot.getValue(FirebaseReq.class);
                service(fbReq);
            }
...
        });
```

For maintanance and readability is for me much more clear this:

```
Run service(fbReq) in new thread.

 public void service(FirebaseReq firebaseReq) {
            value = dao(firebaseReq);
            /*some other code which use value*/
 }

public String dao(FirebaseReq firebaseReq) {
        String result = null;
        //the second firebase call
        childRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
               result = snapshot.getName();
            }
          ...
       });
        while (result== null){
        }   
        return result;
}
```

Or is better avoid threads and waiting loop, but with unreadability code:

```
 public void service(FirebaseReq firebaseReq) {
     ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
               /*some other code which use value*/
            }
          ...
       });
     dao(firebaseReq,valueEventListener);              
 }

public String dao(FirebaseReq firebaseReq,ValueEventListener valueEventListener) {
        //the second firebase call
        childRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
}
```

Thanks for reply

Comment: A loop while `while (result == null) { }` could chew up a lot of processor time.  If you decide to do it this way, consider using methods like [wait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) and [notify](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) instead of a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Async callbacks are almost always preferred to a wait. Especially a busy wait as you are using.

I find your callback code cleaner in fact.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any pattern for using async callbacks? Or is my code fine?